# The car engages gears but does not move and when i depress the clutch it also sounds like grinding metal

Tags: mazda, manual-transmission

Mazda rx8 , 2004
13b
Manual Transmission
6 speed

Comment: Its either a bad clutch or transmission, you would have to pull the transmission in either case to repair it.

Comment: Are you asking what's going on, or are you asking what you should do fix it? The question part of this is very unclear.